# How to adjust Cycles color balance

Tags: cycles-render-engine, color-management

The color an object appears can be set using a *Black Body* node, which accurately simulates the color an object should have. This is however relative to the color balance/white balance used. An object will appear blue if it's "temperature" is 6000K if the image is balanced at 4500K (and 4500K appears white); If, however, it's balanced at 8000K, the same object will appear yellow/red.

[image]

Is there a way to adjust the color balance temperature?

Comment: Do you want to adjust the color temperature for the rendered image?

Comment: @stacker Yes, indeed

Comment: You could probably do that in Photoshop camera raw.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure this means the same as color temperature: in the *Scenes's properties* is a checkbox *Use Curves*

The [release notes](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.64/Color_Management) only mention

> RGB Curves Curves to control image colors before color space
>   conversion.

[image]

http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/User:Sobotka/Color_Management